# How do i get a daily notification?

Tags: notifications

I'd like my phone to give me a daily notification to remind me to do something. This something isn't time *critical*, I just need to remember to do it of an evening. Therefore, I don't want to use the alarm function and be interrupted in the middle of doing something else - I just want a notification to appear at a given time.

Ideally any solution should avoid having a constant notification visible, which rules out most of the apps I've tried.

I *could* just send myself a daily email (as I have a raspberry pi), but I tried that, and the email notification gets lost in with other emails.

I've also tried using notify.run, which only seems to work sporadically.

Any ideas as to how I might achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried a repeating calendar event?

Comment: Have you tried Google Keep? You can swipe the notification away when you are done with it. I use it for daily reminders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot more googling, I found this can be achieved with Google reminders. To find them, there's an app called "Google" on the phone. In that app there's a hamburger menu which has reminders under it.